# Kivy Python "Invalid Indentation (too many levels)?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

When i take the label "id:meaning" out of the code it runs fine. I cant see where the indentation is incorrect. Can anyone help, please?

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

[image: SECTION OF CODE WITH ERROR]

**solved** Click the Format tab in IDLE then click toggle tabs. It fixed the spacing issue.

Comment: Please post the code as text rather than an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete all the spaces and line feeds before and after lines 44, 45 and 46 and be sure to insert the right indentation characters

Sometimes this errors are not enough clear. It happends that there is a problem in the line before or after the one indicated

Comment: Your correct, when I copy an existing label and modify it, the program runs error free. I have to press the tab button 6 times to get the existing codes indentation which is only 3 tabs. I dont know how that has happened or how to fix it, can anyone help yet again? p.s. thank you Jorge Henrique and theBugger :-)

Comment: I don't recognise your editor, but in IDLE for example in the `Format` menu there's the `untabify` command which fixes this kind of typos

Answer (score 1):

Python needs a 4-space indent.

Try to trim excess spaces and tabs from ends of lines, and remove empty lines at the end of files. Also ensure the last line ends with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i was running my kivy project, but i later learnt that you should make sure that your lines of code are uniformly corrected to the right indent and they are no white space. The kivy language code submitted below runs perfectly.

:
cons: 2
rows: 2

```
 Label:
      text: "My Name is?"
      font_size: 50

 TextInput:
      text: "Enter your name"
      font_size: 50

 Button:
      text: "Submit"
```